# Spinner Android Studio

Tags: android

Estou colocando um `Spinner` no meu projeto, e queria colocar um tipo de hint nele e alterar a cor da fundo dele.

Por exemplo:
ao entrar na tela, vai esta escrito "Selecione", e ao abrir o `Spinner`, o "Selecione" deve estar com a cor de fundo diferente das opções, para tipo separar o titulo das opções.

Comment: A sua pergunta foi editada por uso indevido da tag [android-studio](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info)

Comment: Teria como você detalhar melhor o seu problema? Tem alguma imagem que ilustre o que você quer fazer?

Comment: Por exemplo:<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="10"               android:prompt="@string/title"
            android:dropDownSelector="@drawable/card_master"
            tools:listheader="@layout/custom_textview_spinner_color_text"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_input_white"/>

Mas o prompt nao esta dando certo, tentei tambem o spinnerColorChange.setPrompt("Titulo");  mas tambem nao deu certo.